# Vertical and horizontal paging with dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, paging

Is it possible to do vertical **and** horizontal paging in iOS with dynamic content? That is, the number of pages in any of the 4 directions and content data would be fetched at run-time from a web-service.